# JSON file from API to a hive table

Tags: json, curl, hive

I loaded the curl output of an API into a JSON file. I now want to create a HIVE table using the JSON file but unable to do so which I believe is because of the format of my JSON file (example below).

Please advise me on how to get the data loaded from this JSON file to a table

```
{
  "key" : 10
  "key2":3
}

{
  "key" : 20
  "key4":4
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you tried to load the data into table?

Answer (score 0):

These examples are not correct. You are missing a comma to separate pairs.

HIVE supports JSON files via this serialisation library  https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde